# Multiple Text Lines as Watermark on image in java

Tags: java, image, awt, watermark

I want to print a specific format as watermark on decoded image in java such as timestamp,latitude ,longitude on image . I have created a watermarkformat pojo class for it.
Now i want to watermark that particular format on decoded/rendered image , but Graphics2D drawString() method takes String and x,y coordinates. How shall i convert my object in to string to pass to drawString()

Look at the following code -

BufferedImage watermarked = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, imageType);

```
    // initializes necessary graphic properties
    Graphics2D w = (Graphics2D) watermarked.getGraphics();
    w.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    AlphaComposite alphaChannel = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.4f);
    w.setComposite(alphaChannel);
    w.setColor(Color.RED);
    w.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12));
    w.drawString(text,100,70); // here i want alternative method which takes watermarkformat object or any alternative way 
    ImageIO.write(watermarked, type, destination);
    w.dispose();
```

please help what could be the alternative way to print specific format on image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are talking about is a multi-line watermark then you may want to try this to replace your current w.drawString() method:

```
// If the text is in a single string with newline characters in it
for (String line : text.split("\n")) {
    w.drawString(line, x, y += w.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```

---

```
// If the text is in a String Array named: text[]
for (String line : text) {
    w.drawString(line, x, y += w.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```